# Get git + ssh to work without user owned .ssh/config

Tags: ssh, git

### What's wrong

At the moment, git gives me:

```
Bad owner or permissions on ~/.ssh/config
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

when I try to pull a repo.

### Why I'm not just going to do what the error message seems to want

As part of hardening a server (which updates its codebase using git), I've designated one user to manage the (readonly) repo keys and the other user to actually download the repo and run the code.

It's a nice setup, and I like it. But as a consequence the permissions are along the lines of:

```
-rw-r-----  key_manager  repo_slurper
```

If I changed the owner to repo_slurper and the perms to 0600, it would be another thing I'd have to manually keep track of which I shouldn't need to manually keep track of if the permissions are tuned right.

Additionally, repo_slurper does not have cron permissions, but I do have a cron job that pulls the repo as that user. If I let the user handle ssh config, and that user is compromised, they can subtly mess things up on a regularly-scheduled basis.

### Codicil

If you see anything problematic in the security policy which leads me to this issue, let me know. If the security policy is unsound and it leads to this issue, I am not opposed to changing the policy.

Comment: Any reason not to use something like `gitolite3`? It handles permissions (down to branch level if needed) efficiently and can be strongly secured using SELinux.

Comment: It seems to me that the real issue is that your deployment strategy is wrong. How about installing [Teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) on the server that does the deploying. Add the key of the server to your allowed keys of the repo and add the key of the deployment server to the server that needs updating and your all set.

Comment: Both of these are good solutions, and after I've had more time to look over them I'll probably switch to one in a few weeks (after I've had a chance to test them and look up their security track records). This solution still seems like the simplest one at the moment, though.